# Onclick Word Replacement not working correctly with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, quotes

I have this code:

`<a class='show' data-id='".$random."' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='if(this.innerHTML == 'Click Here to Read More'){this.innerHTML = 'Click Here to Read Less'}else{this.innerHTML = 'Click Here to Read More'}'>Click Here to Read More</a>`

When the page is returned though everything is returned weird and items are missing in source code like so:

```
<a class="show" onclick="if(this.innerHTML == " href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="23272317" }'="" }else{this.innerhtml="Click Here to Read More" more'){this.innerhtml="Click Here to Read Less" read="" to="" here="" click="">Click Here to Read More</a>
```

Im sure its as simple as a quotes issue but im stuck. Anyone able to point me in the right direction or explain how or why this happens with only javascript?

Comment: So, you have `'` which encloses attribute and `'` which encloses a `Click Here`.

Comment: Your `onclick` attribute is quoted with `'`, so the value ends as of the first `'`, so your `onclick` is `onclick='if(this.innerHTML == '`. Either use double quotes (`"`) around the attribute value and single quotes within it, or vice-versa, or use character entities in the value (since attribute text is HTML).

Comment: T.J. Crowder your help was appreciated very much, thank you. I guess I just needed \" instead of " or '. Double quotes weren't fixing the issue either when I swapped them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you output this code with `echo`:

```
echo "<a class='show' data-id='".$random."' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='if(this.innerHTML == \"Click Here to Read More\"){this.innerHTML = \"Click Here to Read Less\"} else {this.innerHTML = \"Click Here to Read More\"}'>Click Here to Read More</a>";
```

Note that I replaced `'` around `Click Here to ...` to escaped `"` because:

- `'` is already used in enclosing attribute data
- `"` enclose full string that you `echo`